# Gorm field User: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Tags: postgresql, go, model, go-gorm

This is my first time using Gorm, and when I run my server, this error keeps popping out.

```
[error] invalid field found for struct github.com/Dokito555/mp3-player-backend/internal/models.Music's field User: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

i read the gorm documentation and implement what im missing
here's the music model

```
type Music struct {
    Base
    Title     string     `json:"title"`
    Alttitle  string     `json:"alt_title"`
    Approved  bool       `json:"approved"`
    Streams   int        `json:"streams"`
    User      User       `json:"user" gorm:"foreignKey:UserRefer;references:UserID"`
    UserID    string     `json:"user_id"`
    Album     Album      `json:"albums" gorm:"foreignKey:AlbumRefer;references:AlbumID"`
    AlbumID   string     `json:"album_id"`
    Artists   []Artist   `json:"artist" gorm:"many2many:music_artists;"`
    Playlists []Playlist `json:"playlists" gorm:"many2many:music_playlists;"`
}
```

and here's the user model

```
type User struct {
    Base
    Email       string      `json:"email" gorm:"unique"`
    Username    string      `json:"username" gorm:"unique"`
    Password    string      `json:"password"`
    Role        int         `json:"role"`
    Music       []Music     `json:"music" gorm:"many2many:user_musics;"`
    Playlist    []Playlist  `json:"playlist" gorm:"many2many:user_playlists;"`
}
```

the error is still there when i run my server, any solution to this problem?